# Is there any way to obfuscate a flutter plugin before publishing it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I am coming from native android development and wanted to know how you can obfuscate a flutter plugin before publishing it (just a plugin not the final app). In native android development for libraries we basically build .aar artifact with proguard, this helps in obfuscation. I tried searching for same in flutter but all I could find was how to [obfuscate the final app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate) and not the plugin itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to obfuscate a flutter plugin code as it is open-source and dart doesn't support obfuscation. But if you need to secure your dart code then better not to publish it to the pub.dev and keep it privately.